# Can I add a custom link to "Main Menu" via hook_menu?

Tags: 7, routes

I'm trying to add a new link to the Main Menu from inside my module.

Currently, this code:

```
function custom_food_orders_menu() {
  $items['order_food'] = array(
    'title' => 'Order Food',
    'page callback' => 'page_creator_function',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
        'menu_name=' => 'main-menu',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

...adds the 'order food' link to the 'Navigation' menu. I tried setting the menu name to main-menu, but that does not seem to work.

Is this a limitation in Drupal? If it is, I'll adjust by creating a link to that page manually.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The correct code would be the following one; notice the commented line.

```
function custom_food_orders_menu() {
  $items['order_food'] = array(
    'title' => 'Order Food',
    'page callback' => 'page_creator_function',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'menu_name' => 'main-menu',  // This is the changed line.
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

There aren't properties returned from `hook_menu()` (and generally from any hook used from Drupal core code) that uses the equal character.