# How to add a menu item to main menu: hook_menu() or menu_link_save()?

Tags: 7, hooks, navigation

I just want to programmatically add some menu items to the main menu, but none of the answers I found worked. Some answers suggest using `hook_menu()`, others suggest using `menu_link_save()`. I followed what reported in [Can I add a custom link to "Main Menu" via hook_menu?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26946/can-i-add-a-custom-link-to-main-menu-via-hook-menu) but it just doesn't work. There's no new item added, neither in the UI nor in the database.

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['my/path'] = array(
    'title' => 'Title',
    'page callback' => 'page_creator_function',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Also I found [How and where do I programmatically add a menu to the Navigation menu?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14902/how-and-where-do-i-programmatically-add-a-menu-to-the-navigation-menu). Answer #2 says that using `menu_link_save()` is the way to go, but I could not get it to work. Do I have to place the code in a certain location or a special hook?

```
$item = array(
  'link_path' => 'my_path',
  'link_title' => 'Title',
  'menu_name' => 'main-menu', 
  'weight' => 0,
  'language' => 'en',
  'plid' => 0,
  'module' => 'menu',
);
menu_link_save($item);
```

Since both answers didn't work out, it seems that I am missing a crucial point. Could anyone say what's going on here?

Comment: your first hook should work, so if the menu item doesn't show, try to clear all caches and if no joy, try to debug and see where the error might lie... for example add a dpm inside your hook to see if it's even being called.

Comment: As side note, in the second snippet you show there is a missing string delimiter, in the third line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a hard time I figured out what hampered the execution of the above code: clearing caches isn't enough to see the results. I had to use devels menu reset (/devel/menu/reset). Using drush's `drush eval 'menu_rebuild();'` as mentioned at [How do I call the menu_rebuild function in Drupal 7?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58618/how-do-i-call-the-menu-rebuild-function-in-drupal-7/124596) somehow does not work. I do not know why.